# (Homestead) Vagrant up throws undefined method

Tags: laravel, vagrant, virtualbox

I'm trying to set up virtual machine using Laravel's Homestead.
When I run vagrant up it fails on following error:

```
C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/util/network_ip.rb:24:in `ip_parts': undefined method `split' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

I tried reinstalling vagrant as well as making a fresh copy of homestead, but with no luck.

So here are the contents of my Vagrantfile:

```
VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

path = "#{File.dirname(__FILE__)}"

require 'yaml'
require path + '/scripts/homestead.rb'

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
  Homestead.configure(config, YAML::load(File.read(path + '/Homestead.yaml')))
end
```

and Homestead.yaml

```
---
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1

authorize: C:/keys/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - C:/keys/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: C:/development
      to: /home/vagrant/code

sites:
    - map: workshop-director.local
      to: /home/vagrant/code/workshop-director/public

variables:
    - key: APP_ENV
      value: development
```

And here is the full error message:

```
C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/util/network_ip.rb:24:in `ip_parts': undefined method `split' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
    from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/util/network_ip.rb:8:in `network_address'
    from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/network.rb:264:in `block in hostonly_config'
    from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/network.rb:263:in `each'
    from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/network.rb:263:in `hostonly_config'
    from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/network.rb:89:in `block in call'
    from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/network.rb:82:in `each'
    from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/network.rb:82:in `call'
    from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/clear_network_interfaces.rb:26:in `call'
    from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/prepare_nfs_settings.rb:15:in `call'
    from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/synced_folders.rb:84:in `call'
    from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/synced_folder_cleanup.rb:28:in `call'
    from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/plugins/synced_folders/nfs/action_cleanup.rb:19:in `call'
    from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/prepare_nfs_valid_ids.rb:12:in `call'
    from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/handle_forwarded_port_collisions.rb:160:in `handle'
    from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/handle_forwarded_port_collisions.rb:42:in `block in call'
    from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:474:in `lock'
    from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/handle_forwarded_port_collisions.rb:41:in `call'
    from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/prepare_forwarded_port_collision_params.rb:30:in `call'
    from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/env_set.rb:19:in `call'
    from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/provision.rb:80:in `call'
    from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/clear_forwarded_ports.rb:15:in `call'
    from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/set_name.rb:50:in `call'
    from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/clean_machine_folder.rb:17:in `call'
    from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/check_accessible.rb:18:in `call'
    from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:95:in `block in finalize_action'
    from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116:in `call'
    from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `block in run'
    from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
    from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `run'
    from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/call.rb:53:in `call'
    from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:95:in `block in finalize_action'
    from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116:in `call'
    from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `block in run'
    from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
    from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `run'
    from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/call.rb:53:in `call'
    from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:95:in `block in finalize_action'
    from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116:in `call'
    from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `block in run'
    from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
    from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `run'
    from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/call.rb:53:in `call'
    from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/box_check_outdated.rb:68:in `call'
    from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/config_validate.rb:25:in `call'
    from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/check_virtualbox.rb:17:in `call'
    from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:95:in `block in finalize_action'
    from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/match_mac_address.rb:16:in `call'
    from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/import.rb:32:in `call'
    from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/customize.rb:40:in `call'
    from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/check_accessible.rb:18:in `call'
    from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:95:in `block in finalize_action'
    from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116:in `call'
    from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `block in run'
    from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
    from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `run'
    from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/call.rb:53:in `call'
    from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/config_validate.rb:25:in `call'
    from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:95:in `block in finalize_action'
    from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/handle_box.rb:56:in `call'
    from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:95:in `block in finalize_action'
    from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116:in `call'
    from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `block in run'
    from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
    from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `run'
    from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/call.rb:53:in `call'
    from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/check_virtualbox.rb:17:in `call'
    from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116:in `call'
    from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `block in run'
    from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
    from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `run'
    from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:196:in `action_raw'
    from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:173:in `block in action'
    from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:474:in `lock'
    from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:161:in `call'
    from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:161:in `action'
    from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/batch_action.rb:82:in `block (2 levels) in run'
```

Comment: could you please post some more samples of the Vagrant file and provisioning scripts? The "undefined method blah for nil:NilClass" sounds like you have not passed a valid IP address where one is expected...

Comment: I dont have access to my files right now, so I'll post it later, but for what I can say at the moment, I have not changed the default IP in Homestead.yaml, which as I recall is 192.168.10.10. The only things I have changed in configs were the site path and ssh key path.

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm right about this, but it also seems that when running vagrant up every process runs several times. FOr example at the begining I get:
4.3.18r96516
4.3.18r96516
4.3.18r96516

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out the source of the problem was not Vagrant but PowerCmd terminal I was using. When I run vagrant from normal Windows console it all runs fine, but for some reason in PowerCmd it fails. 
I still have no clue why this is the case, but at least the original issue is fixed.